# Drop down list with Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I code an html page with a drop-down list with HTML CSS and VueJS. I want that if I click on a certain option in my drop-down list, it display something in console.

My html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/historique.js"></script>

    <title>Historique</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selectionMachines" size="1">
        <option v-for="todo in todos"  v-on:click="action">
            {{ todo.libelle }}
        </option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS code :

```
window.onload = function () {
    var machines = new Vue({
        el:"#selectionMachines",
        data: {
            todos: [
                { libelle: "Machine 195", num: 195},
                { libelle: "Machine 196", num: 195}
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            action: function() {
                console.log(this.todo.num);
                if (this.todos.num == 195)
                    console.log("J'ai choisi 195");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The action function doesn't work for the moment,  undefined is log in console. Any idea ?

Comment: Your data is called `todos` your writing `this.todo.num` within your `action: function()`

Comment: `this.todos` is an Array, so `this.todos.num` will never be the num property from one of the items in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<option v-for="todo in todos" @click="action(todo)">
            {{ todo.libelle }} 
</option>
```

```
action(todo) { if (todo.num === 195) console.log("J'ai choisi 195"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The event should be bound to `<select>`.
2. The event should pass the `$event` variable to the function
3. The options' values should be bound to the options themselves (`:value=""`). You'll get this value with the `$event` (`$event.target.value`)
4. Even though you literally click on a `<select>` and the `<option>`, the event is not `click()`, but `input` or `change`, as it's an input field. This is not VueJS question, but JavaScript.
5. Your `action()` method is a function, so if you want it to get executed, then you have to call it with parantheses (`action()`), and not it's "string value" (`action`). This is unlike *computed* in VueJS templates, but VueJS handles the difference.
6. Pay attention to your `todos` - both have a `num` key with value **195** (so you won't see a difference in the console, both will log **195** there), although their label (`libelle`) implies 195 and 196
7. You write `console.log(this.todo.num);` and `this.todos.num == 195` in your `action()` method. I guess you tried to use the single **todo** item that's selected in the input. The problem with this is that the `input` (and the `todo in todos`) only exist in your template, your scripts (like `methods`) don't know about them - you have to pass the information somehow to those scripts (`$event` is good for that). If you want to get the whole single todo object to work with, then I suggest `find()` (or `filter()` as your `num` value is not unique).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#selectionMachines",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        libelle: "Machine 195",
        num: 195
      },
      {
        libelle: "Machine 196",
        num: 195
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    action: function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<select id="selectionMachines" size="1" @change="action($event)">
  <option v-for="todo in todos" :value="todo.num">
    {{ todo.libelle }}
  </option>
</select>
```